# How would one write a proof that this summation including only a number and it's reverse always add up to the same integer for any number of digits?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, recursion

So, according to [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_j5v882T7V8): if you reverse a number, the subtract the reversal from the original number to get oh say x, then you add x to the reversal of x you always get 1089.

I also notice that if the reversal subtracted from the original number is  negative, you then *subtract* the reversal of that sum from itself and then you get negative 1089.

For two digit numbers following the process always seems to add up to 99 or -99!

This rule is broken for palindromes, at least at first glance.

(Remember, leading zeros: ie, 9 becomes 09->90.)

You could write some software pretty easily to test all of these cases and beyond, but I'm not sure the results would be very insightful.

I assume this is like the 9's trick, with equivalents in other bases but I haven't been able to generalize it...

Does anyone have a more general proof of why this works?

Answer (score 1):

Say $n = a_1a_2a_3$ is a 3-digit number with $a_1 \geq a_3$ (so the reversal isn't bigger, just for simplicity; we don't lose any generality), and also that $a_1 > 0$. So $n = a_1 \cdot 100 + a_2\cdot 10 + a_3$. Then $x$ is
$$a_1(100 - 1) + a_2(10 - 10) + a_3(1 - 100) = 99(a_1 - a_3)$$
From here, there are only 10 cases to check (and you saw that it breaks for palindromes). If a three-digit multiple of 99 is positive, it has a 9 in the penultimate digit (consider $99y \equiv -y$ mod 100; since $y < 10$ as we're three digits, we're a multiple of 100 minus something less than 10). Then, its digits must add to 9, so the first and third sum to 9 total. So when we add it to its reverse, we get a 9 in the last place (first and third add to 9), an 8 in the second (9 and 9 add to 18), a 0 in the third (third and first add to 9, carry the 1), and the carry in the most significant slot. 1089. This is also the reverse of $99^2$ if you really want to mess with people, I don't know if the video mentions this.

This breaks in larger number of digits since we lose the property of $x$ being a nice multiple of 99.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the rule does not work for palindromes which is why we have $a>c$ below.

Let $n=100a+10b+c$ for digits $a,b,c$ with $a>c$. Then the reversal is $100c+10b+a$ and the difference (after carries) is
$$100(a-c-1)+90+(10+c-a).$$

Adding this number to its reversal i.e.
$$100(10+c-a)+90+(a-c-1)$$
gives 
$$900+180+9=1089.$$

Answer (score 0):

**An extension to any number of digits**

All that is required is for each digit on the left of the number to be greater than the corresponding digit on the right.

So for a 5 digit number written as 
$$abcde$$we require $a>e$ and $b>d$. The process then always gives $$109890.$$

If the number of digits of our initial number is odd and greater than $1$, then the answer is always $$10*89*$$ where the RH $*$ is a string of 0s and the LH $*$ is a string of an equal number of 9s. (These strings are empty for 3 digit numbers.)

If the number of digits of our initial number is even and greater than $2$, then the answer is always $$10*89*$$ where the RH $*$ is a string of 0s and the LH $*$ is a string of one fewer 9s.

You might like to prove these results for different numbers of digits using the same idea as in the answer to the post.